# Serial Port Terminal

Tags: c, uart, mplab

I am programming a MAX32 Micro controller in MPLAB. I want to use the UART protocol to interact with my terminal (I am developing on a mac). Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read Wikipedia UART Article
2. Read Reference Manual of your µC, Chapter "...UART..."
3. Get example Code for this issue from your Reference Manual or Programming Manual or Internet Articles
4. Program your board
5. Connect your Board with your PC via Cable (USB, RS232 to USB (virtual RS232) or UART to USB)
6. Open Terminal Program i.e. TeraTerm
7. Check your Settings i.e. Baud Rate
8. Try it